# Django transaction using multi-db

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have three database and I want to adding data to they in transactions on one request.

For example my code.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def my_view(request):
    try:
        MyModel_one(...).save(using='default')
        MyModel_two(...).save(using='db_one')
        MyModel_three(...).save(using='db_two') # <-- for example we make exception here (duplicate data)
    except IntegrityError:
        transaction.rollback()
        transaction.rollback(using='db_one')
        transaction.rollback(using='db_two')
        return ...
    transaction.commit()
    transaction.commit(using='db_one')
    transaction.commit(using='db_two')
    return ...
```

Result:

1. MyModel_one — data didn't saved
2. MyModel_two — data saved (I didn't understand why)
3. MyModel_three — data didn't save because hope error

question: Why transaction didn't work here ? What can I do to get work transaction ?

(I try to use other ways but didn't have success result)
(Also I understand it's not beutiful code but very simple for understanding the problem)

Django 1.7.7
Python 2.7

Database:
default — postgres
db_one — mysql
db_two — mysql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`transaction.commit_manually`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_manually) decorator [was deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.6/#transaction-management-apis) in Django 1.6. You should switch to Django's new transaction management.

I don't think you need to commit transactions manually, you can nest [`transaction.atomic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic).

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        with transaction.atomic(using='default'):
            with transaction.atomic(using='db_one'):
                with transaction.atomic(using='db_two'):
                    MyModel_one(...).save(using='default')
                    MyModel_two(...).save(using='db_one')
                    MyModel_three(...).save(using='db_two') # raises exception
    except IntegrityError:
        return ...
    return ...
```

Comment: Data success saved in MyModel_tow table of database 'db_one'. I don't understand why they saved.

Comment: I've changed my answer, and moved the atom blocks inside the try except. Could you try that?

Comment: I find solution. Problem in table type. myisam didn't support transaction.

Comment: How does this guarantees transaction across the 3 dbs? The commit sequence would be db_two, db_one, default. Transaction will not be committed together at the outer most block as transaction only operates on a particular connection. If commit to db_one fail, db_two is already committed, thus the transaction is not fully rolled back?

Comment: @Yituo it's a while since I wrote this answer, but it looks like it will work it the exception is raised inside the inner atomic block (e.g. on the line `MyModel_three(...).save(using='db_two')` like in the original question). If the exception is raised when committing the transaction to `db_one`, then as you say, `db_two` has already been committed. Handling that is a harder problem, and I don't have a solution.

Comment: i think two deal with distributed transactions we need to use 2 phase commit method or 3 phase or saga in this case i think 2 phase will do the job