# DJANGO multi db transaction with nested transaction.atomic

Tags: django, database, transactions, sharding

I've been searching a good way to implement cross db transaction in DJANGO, but there seem to be no good answer. I would want to support something like

```
with transaction.atomic(): # cross shard transaction 
    # update obj1 and update obj2
    obj1.save(using=db_shard1)
    obj2.save(using=db_shard2)
```

Both db_shard1 and db_shard2 are postgres dbs

I did see this post [Django transaction using multi-db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31928143/django-transaction-using-multi-db) which suggested using nested trasaction.atomic(using='different_data_base_name'). However I wonder how does this work. With each nested block, django identifies a different connection, and all the checks and operations are performed specific to this connection, so I think the nested transaction.atomic could not guarantee cross-db transaction.

Could someone help me understand why the nested transaction.atomic could work? Or if not, any suggestions on how to go about it?

Comment: You can’t guarantee multiple transactions across multiple connections will be atomic since they will be committed serially. What is your use case for this?

Comment: My use case is to support cross db (actually sharded db) writes in single transaction.

Comment: How is the sharding and the multi DB configured? Can you share the model(s), settings and code that writes to the DB